# Automatically print html to pdf

Tags: javascript, html

I have an app that generate html file with A4 file size, I want this file automatically print to pdf when people open it, I've tried something like this, but it only open print dialog, not automatically download it

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Call the window.print() method to initiate printing once the document has loaded
    window.print();
};
```

I already tried many library but the result is not same with the html, any suggestion?

Comment: " I want this file automatically print to pdf when people open it" .... Not supported. The user must always manually ok a print.

Comment: Imagine a world where any webpage you visit could send any job it wants to your printer without your consent...

Comment: @David yeah I know, my client want it to work that way, I just want to make sure is it possible

Comment: Nope, it's also not possible to bypass the print dialog.

Comment: @RaihanRahman: In that case your client may be looking for a custom browser extension or custom application.  In-browser JavaScript alone can't do this.